# How to send a mail when someone remote connects to my server

Tags: shell-script, ssh, email, monitoring

I would like my server to send a mail to me when someone connects remotely over `ssh` to my server.

`who` only gives me back the Username, TerminalID and Date. I cannot use only that, I need to check for the IP someone uses to connect to me.
So the triggering part would be an external IP.

**How can I achieve that?**

EDIT: who -h gives back the IP adresses of the ssh sessions. Thanks to Archemar

Comment: `who -u` give you more usefull information (like IP).

Comment: Ok, who -u gives back the IP's thats great. Do you also know who I can execute a script when a SSH Login happens?

Comment: A generic solution using PAM is described [in this blog entry](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some shell scripting to `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` maybe bepending on your linux distribution. Those are executed when user logs in remotely via SSH. Just test if there is `$SSH_CLENT` variable to distinguish the ssh login.

There will be other usefull variables for your needs, like:

```
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass
SSH_CLIENT='127.0.0.1 57353 2217' ← ip address
SSH_CONNECTION='127.0.0.1 57353 127.0.0.1 2217'
USER=username
```

EDIT:
Of course, if the user is using GNU/bash. Other shells uses other files.
Check them in related manuals.

HTH, Cheers

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through all this at the evening when I have some more time.

Comment: It worked pretty well Scyld, I just have make some more tweaks and I'll have what I want. Thanks to you!